# How to create arrow buttons in Excel to scroll the table left and right?

Tags: excel

There is an Excel document with a table, where there are a lot of columns (which do not fit on the screen). Is it possible to navigate to the rightmost and leftmost column of a table using macros? The number of columns is not constant, because this is a pivot table - the first day has 20 columns, the second day has 50, and so on.

The sheet already has up and down buttons with the following macros:

```
Sub TableDown()
Application.SendKeys ("^{END}") 'moves to bottom of table
End Sub

Sub TableUp()
Application.SendKeys ("^{HOME}") 'moves to top of table
End Sub
```

Is it possible to implement scrolling to the left and right edges of the table in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-shift-home goes to the upper-left of all columns, and ctrl-shift-end goes to bottom-right of all columns. Hopefully that helps some.

Comment: It did not help. Ctrl-shift-home selected all cells above the selected cell. ctrl-shift-end selected all cells below and to the right above the selected cell

Comment: Weird, for me no matter where my cursor is in the sheet it's just popping the cursor to the upper left or bottom right, and not selecting anything.

Comment: One shortcut is if you hold ctrl and use your middle scroll button on mouse you can drastically zoom in, and then just use horizontal scroll bar on bottom to go to left or right side of sheet. One other tip, if you hold down shift you can scroll extra fast. All this is assuming you're on windows.

Comment: Still, I need the buttons to quickly jump to the extreme right and extreme left columns. And I need to assign appropriate macros to them.